# How can I stream a Map<String, List<Object>> into a Stream<Entry<String, Object>>?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, query-string

I have a `Map<String, List<Object>>`.

How can I make it into a Stream of `Entry<String, Object>` so that I can construct a concatenated query `String`?

```
q1    a, b
q2    c, d
```

into

```
q1=a&q1=b&q2=c&q2=d
```

I'm, currently, doing this.

```
if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
    final boolean[] flag = new boolean[1];
    params.forEach((n, vs) -> {
        vs.forEach(v -> {
            builder.append(flag[0] ? '&' : '?')
                    .append(n)
                    .append('=')
                    .append(v);
            if (!flag[0]) {
                flag[0] = true;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Side remark: Don't forget to UrlEncode your names and values when constructing the query string manually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you don't have to produce a `Entry<String, Object>`. You can use `flatMap` to obtain the key=value `String`s and directly construct the query `String` using `Collectors.joining`:

```
String query =
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> e.getKey() + '=' + v))
       .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
```

Input :

```
{q1=[a, b], q2=[c, d]}
```

Output :

```
q1=a&q1=b&q2=c&q2=d
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have Guava, you might want to consider using a `ListMultimap<String, Object>` instead of `Map<String, List<Object>>`, and create your string like so:

```
String query = Joiner.on("&").withKeyValueSeparator("=").join(map.entries());
```